# p->data = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)); compare to (int*)p->data = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

Tags: c, gcc, malloc

```
typedef struct _DListNode
{
    struct _DListNode* prev;
    struct _DListNode* next;
    void*  data;
}DListNode;
```

in gcc :

```
DListNode *p = NULL;

p = (DListNode*)malloc(sizeof(DListNode));

p->data = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));   

scanf("%d", (int*)p->data);
```

compile correctly.

in gcc :

```
DListNode *p = NULL;

p = (DListNode*)malloc(sizeof(DListNode));

(int*)p->data = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)); 

scanf("%d", (int*)p->data);
```

There is a problem on :

```
(int*)p->data = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)); -------error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment.
```

the difference:

```
scanf("%d", (int*)p->data) ,

(int*)p->data = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)),

p->data = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Comment: You shouldn't cast from `malloc` in either case - the cast from `void*` is implicit in C.

Comment: Not to mention, that `data` is of type `void*`, so cast from `malloc` is a pure nonsense.

Comment: Note: That identifiers that begin with an underscore and a capiol letter are reserved. So technically the above is not valid: '_DListNode'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `(int*&)p->data = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));`"?

(int *) gives the pointer value itself, i.e. it's akin to saying `0x12345678 = malloc(sizeof(int));`.

Btw, mallocing for something as small as an int is extremely wasteful.

EDIT:

1. This might only work in C++, not C.
2. Why do you cast in the first place? You're assigning a void pointer to a void pointer. Isn't that convenient? Why cast?
3. If you really want to amuse yourself, you could do something silly like `*(int **) &(p->data) = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));`. Nonsense, right? Right. Just assign the value. Better yet, replace your data with a union.

Comment: It does work in C++, my C is a bit rusty. I don't see the point of casting in the first place anyway.

Comment: C definitely doesn't have references, so your `(int*&)` would be a syntax error.  I'm surprised `(int*&)p->data` is an lvalue in C++, but I don't know all of the minutiae there.

Comment: It is, it's basically a reference to the pointer, so you can modify it. Again, this whole approach is kind of backwards to begin with. There shouldn't be a cast, and there preferably shouldn't be a malloc.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the statements is that it doesn't make sense to try and specify the pointer type on the left-hand-side of an expression which is what you're doing in the `(int*)p->data` case because `p->data` is always a `void*` as defined in the structure. When the compiler sees this it assumes you're casting it to an `int*` so that you can read it, i.e. it becomes an r-value, a value which is only valid on the right-hand-side of an assignment expression not an l-value (left-hand-side) which can be assigned to.

If you want to read / write an integer value stored in `p->data` then I think the clearest syntax is `*((int*)(p->data))` - i.e. take the `p->data` pointer, cast it to an `int*` and then dereference that - but I'm sure you can lose some of the brackets due to the precendence rules.

`data` is a void pointer; it doesn't care what you store in it, i.e. your `(int*)` cast on the malloc is effectively wasted; it only cares that you've given it some allocated memory.

Comment: Thanks for everyone answering my question.
 "(int*)p->data case because p->data is always a void* as defined in the structure", I just wander that if I want to store an int value into a unit, I have to use "scanf("%d", (int*)p->data) ", use (int *)to specify.so, why there is no need to use (int*) to specify or tell the "p->data", hey, what you are store is a pointer vale of int*.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a good reason to have a `void*` instead of an `int*` in `struct _DListNode`? If not, change it to `int*` and then you don't need *any* of the casts.  It's always better to make the types be correct in the first place than to sprinkle casts all over your code.

The error you're getting is because you simply cannot put a cast on the left side of an  assignment.  It's against the rules.  You need to read up on what [lvalues and rvalues](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp6m.doc/language/ref/clrc05lvalue.htm) are and what the difference between them is.

Answer (score 0):

type cast() has high Precedence than ->, so your first one is equal to ((int*)p)-data. 
I think that's not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

So, what is your question? And what is that "the difference" section supposed to mean?

So far, you've got the problem with

```
(int*)p->data = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

which is obviously an invalid statement. The compiler has already told you why.

So, once again, what is your question?